# message to be displayed for incomplete forms in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form where in user will enter all of its data to contact us . Now if user fills half of the form and lives in middle  I want to ask him whether he really want to live this page .Is it possible? my form submission is done using ajax post method

Comment: add code so far you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the beforeunload event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload). Here is a quick example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){return "Are you sure?";};
```

It would probably be ideal to detect partial user input and only add the event listener when some input has been entered. You will also want to remove the dialog when input is completed, or the forum is submitted.

Comment: `function(e)` please :>

Comment: @dan: Umm, why? We have no need to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can place validation function prior to ajax call and consider validation's return value to conclude either submit the form or display message using Confirm() function of javascript. onclick of "yes" on confirmation box you can fire ajax call, below is example of confirmation box in javascript.

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page?')) {
    // leave the page
} else {
    // do nothing
}
```